# Laravel user authentication in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm working on my first react-native app, coming from vue-laravel background I was wondering if it's actually possible to use laravel normal auth for my react-native, so far it seems I can succesfully login a user sending their credentials via POST request to my API, however subsequent uses of Auth helper fail, that is I can't get the logged user using Auth::user(), it returns null...

Is this possible to accomplish? I have read about firebase auth but I don't feel like adding another database system to my laravel main Mysql database, truth is I don't know for sure what laravel uses for authentication under the hood so I can't get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tymon/jwt-auth for backend (laravel) and  use the token in frontend(react native)